# How to invoke a directive by using element name?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have a angular directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function()
{
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        myCustomer: "&"
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
        var oldVal;
        function fromUser(value){
            scope.myCustomer()(value, oldVal);
            oldVal = value;
            return value;
        }

        function toUser(value){
            return value;
        }

        ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);

        ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment I invoke this director by using attribute name and bind it to a function:

```
 <input type="text" my-directive="showInput" ng-model="user.name">
```

It works fine but what I want is to use element name, something like this:

```
<my-directive>
```

The problem is I don't know how to bind to a function as I do with the attributes.

Comment: what do you mean by "a function"? You should be able to use the directive as element

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-first-directive

Comment: I edited my code to understand better. I use parsers and formatters to watch for data changes... And when data update, a function is executed, in this case showInput function. And I would like to write the my-directive="showInput" using DOM element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass restrict: 'E' in directive options

```
angular.module("image-management")
    .directive('myDirective', ($modal) => {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
              showInput: '&'  
            },
            template: '',
            link: function(){}
})   

    <my-directive showInput="showInput" ></my-directive>
```

Comment: And how to invoke this directive in html using elements and not attributes. Now I have my-directive="show input" but would like to have something like this <my-directive> with a function

Comment: I have updated my answer please check how to invoke this directive in html

Answer (score 4):

You will need to set 'restrict' to 'E' in your directive definition something like:

```
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'YourController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        restrict: 'E', //<----this is what you want
        templateUrl: 'template.html'
```

Comment: And how to invoke this directive in html using elements and not attributes. Now I have my-directive="show input" but would like to have something like this <my-directive> with a function

Answer (score 1):

`<my-directive some-function="someFunction"></my-directive>`

Then in your directive `link` function, it is accesible through `attr`

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
    // Your logic...
    attr.someFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @sumair answered, you can do:

```
<my-directive showInput="showInput" ></my-directive>
```

But, if you really want to use only

```
<my-directive>
```

AND your directive does not require to have an isolated scope, you can just leave the scope property of the directive definition and reference your `showInput` function directly from inherited scope like so:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function()
{
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    /*scope: { ////// remove this part //////
        myCustomer: "&"
    },*/
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
        var oldVal;
        function fromUser(value){
            scope.showInput()(value, oldVal);
            oldVal = value;
            return value;
        }

        function toUser(value){
            return value;
        }

        ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);

        ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
    }
  }
}
```